# Jquery Sum of all fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate the sum of all fields in a row, It is working but only for the first row and I have multiple rows of same fields with increments.

Here is my Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/udy5x1eo/

And here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.employee').each(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
      var basic_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtMonthlyRate]').val());
      var advance_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtAdvance]').val());
      var recover_comm = parseInt($('input[name^=txtRecovery]').val());
      var sales_comm = parseInt($('input[name^=txtSales]').val());
      var deduction_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtDeduction]').val());
      var adjustment_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtAdjustment]').val());
      var total_sum = ((basic_salary + recover_comm + sales_comm) - (deduction_salary + advance_salary)) + adjustment_salary;
      $('input[name^=txtTotal]').val(total_sum);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I see `ng-controller="customersCrtl"`, then  using jQuery is bad approach

Comment: @Satpal than using invalid `ng-` attributes is also kinky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this working code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.employee input[type="text"]').keypress(function (evt) {
                    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
                    var keyVal = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
                    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
                    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
                    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
                        if (key != " " && key != "(" && key != ")" && keyVal != 8 && keyVal != 37 && keyVal != 39 && keyVal != 46 && keyVal != 48) {
                            var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
                            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                                theEvent.returnValue = false;
                                if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (key != "-") {
                            var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
                            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                                theEvent.returnValue = false;
                                if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                $('.employee input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
                    var total_sum = 0;
                    var inputs = $(this).parents('.employee').find('input[type="text"]');
                    $.each(inputs, function (index, item) {
                        var thisValue = parseFloat($(item).val());
                        thisValue = isNaN(thisValue) ? 0 : thisValue;
                        if (index < inputs.length - 1)
                            if (this.name.indexOf('txtDeduction') > -1 || this.name.indexOf('txtAdvance') > -1)
                                total_sum -= thisValue;
                            else
                                total_sum += thisValue;
                    });
                    inputs.last().val(total_sum);

                });
            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div ng-controller="customersCrtl">
                <!-- Adjustment Code Start -->
                <!-- Heading Data Start -->
                <div class="row parts_title space_bottom" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom:5px;">
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1" style="text-align:left !important;">#</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="text-align:left !important;">Employee#</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="text-align:left !important;">FullName</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">B.Salary</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Advance</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Rec.Comm</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Sal.Comm</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Deduction</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Adjustment</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Total</div>
                </div>
                <!-- Heading Data End -->

                <div class="employee row space_bottom">
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input name="checked1" checked="" type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">E17-00001</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">Employee Name 1</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="50000" name="txtMonthlyRate1" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtAdvance1" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="35" name="txtRecovery1" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="2350" name="txtSales1" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtDeduction1" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtAdjustment1" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="sumtotal form-control input-sm" value="52385" name="txtTotal1" id="sumtotal" type="text"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="employee row space_bottom">
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input name="checked2" checked="" type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">E17-00002</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">Employee Name 2</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="10000" name="txtMonthlyRate2" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtAdvance2" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtRecovery2" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtSales2" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtDeduction2" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtAdjustment2" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="sumtotal form-control input-sm" value="10000" name="txtTotal2" id="sumtotal" type="text"></div>
                </div>

                <!-- Adjustment Code End -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: so on every keystroke let's go 7 times up and down the DOM tree? Is that what you're suggesting? Do you have any better solution in mind?

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar can we limit all the input fields in numeric values including floats and negative values?

Comment: After your update my comment is now: do we need to listen for `keyup` events *times* the length of `.employee` elements? Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @Rita I have updated code to allow only numeric and negative

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I have change it as  $('.employee input[type="text"]').keyup

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `this` inside `each` loop to individually get/set text field values

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.employee').each(function() {
    var self = this;
    $('input[type="text"]', self).keyup(function() {
      var basic_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtMonthlyRate]', self).val());
      var advance_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtAdvance]', self).val());
      var recover_comm = parseInt($('input[name^=txtRecovery]', self).val());
      var sales_comm = parseInt($('input[name^=txtSales]', self).val());
      var deduction_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtDeduction]', self).val());
      var adjustment_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtAdjustment]', self).val());
      var total_sum = ((basic_salary + recover_comm + sales_comm) - (deduction_salary + advance_salary)) + adjustment_salary;
      $('input[name^=txtTotal]', self).val(total_sum);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div ng-controller="customersCrtl">
    <!-- Adjustment Code Start -->
    <!-- Heading Data Start -->
    <div class="row parts_title space_bottom" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom:5px;">
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1" style="text-align:left !important;">#</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="text-align:left !important;">Employee#</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="text-align:left !important;">FullName</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">B.Salary</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Advance</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Rec.Comm</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Sal.Comm</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Deduction</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Adjustment</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Total</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Heading Data End -->

    <div class="employee row space_bottom">
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input name="checked1" checked="" type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">E17-00001</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">Employee Name 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" value="50000" name="txtMonthlyRate1" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtAdvance1" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" value="35" name="txtRecovery1" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" value="2350" name="txtSales1" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtDeduction1" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtAdjustment1" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="sumtotal form-control input-sm" value="52385" name="txtTotal1" id="sumtotal" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee row space_bottom">
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input name="checked2" checked="" type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">E17-00002</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">Employee Name 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" value="10000" name="txtMonthlyRate2" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtAdvance2" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtRecovery2" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtSales2" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtDeduction2" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtAdjustment2" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <input class="sumtotal form-control input-sm" value="10000" name="txtTotal2" id="sumtotal" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Adjustment Code End -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working can you limit all the text field to allow only numeric values (negative, positive, float values)? it will be a plus

Comment: instead of `type="number"` attribute can we do it through js

Comment: that's not a good practice. but if you still want to do, try this on each input value `!isNaN(parseFloat(inputValue)) && isFinite(inputValue)` to see if its a valid `number`

Comment: or you could simply fallback to `0` with `|| 0` ... but that's not user-friendly

Comment: @Jag tried the same thing before but isn't working at all

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.employee').each(function() {
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    var container = $(this).closest('.row');
        var basic_salary = parseInt(container.find('input[name^=txtMonthlyRate]').val());
        var advance_salary = parseInt(container.find('input[name^=txtAdvance]').val());
                var recover_comm = parseInt(container.find('input[name^=txtRecovery]').val());
                var sales_comm = parseInt(container.find('input[name^=txtSales]').val());
                var deduction_salary = parseInt(container.find('input[name^=txtDeduction]').val());
                var adjustment_salary = parseInt(container.find('input[name^=txtAdjustment]').val());
        var total_sum = ((basic_salary+recover_comm+sales_comm) - (deduction_salary + advance_salary)) + adjustment_salary;
        container.find('input[name^=txtTotal]').val(total_sum);
});
});
});
```

Comment: No need to `.find()` N times for something you could easily have cached earlier (see @jag's answer)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.employee').on('keyup', 'input[type="text"]', calculateTotal);

  function calculateTotal() {
    var input = $(this).closest('.employee').find('input[type="text"]');
    var sum = 0;
    input.slice(0, input.length - 1).each(function() {
      sum = sum + (+this.value || 0);
    });
    input.last().val(sum);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div ng-controller="customersCrtl">
    <!-- Adjustment Code Start -->
    <!-- Heading Data Start -->
    <div class="row parts_title space_bottom" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom:5px;">
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1" style="text-align:left !important;">#</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="text-align:left !important;">Employee#</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="text-align:left !important;">FullName</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">B.Salary</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Advance</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Rec.Comm</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Sal.Comm</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Deduction</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Adjustment</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Total</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Heading Data End -->

    <div class="employee row space_bottom">
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input name="checked1" checked="" type="checkbox"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">E17-00001</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">Employee Name 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="50000" name="txtMonthlyRate1" type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtAdvance1" type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="35" name="txtRecovery1" type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="2350" name="txtSales1" type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtDeduction1" type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtAdjustment1" type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="sumtotal form-control input-sm" value="52385" name="txtTotal1" id="sumtotal" type="text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee row space_bottom">
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input name="checked2" checked="" type="checkbox"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">E17-00002</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">Employee Name 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="10000" name="txtMonthlyRate2" type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtAdvance2" type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtRecovery2" type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtSales2" type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtDeduction2" type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtAdjustment2" type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="sumtotal form-control input-sm" value="10000" name="txtTotal2" id="sumtotal" type="text"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Adjustment Code End -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Forget about `keyup`, use the `input` event.